# reading snappy file in Java Map reduce

Tags: mapreduce, snappy

Can we use snappy file as input file to Map reduce application without using a Custom Input Class?

I was not able to find any information about this.

Regards,
Nish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that but you may have to decompress the file first to use it.

```
 CompressionCodec codec = (CompressionCodec) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(SnappyCodec.class, new Configuration());
```

After creating an instance of codec, call createInputStream and pass the hadoop path.
codec.createInputStream